# Create a Cross Site Lookup in a declarative way

Tags: 2010, lookup-column, xml

I can declare a lookup field with this line:

```
<Field ID="{3EA24157-1C11-41CB-AA01-5EEEF93C2603}"
      Name="NewField"
      DisplayName="New Field"
      StaticName="NewField"
      DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE"
      Group="New Columns"
      ShowField="ID"
      List="Lists/Cars"
      WebId="~sitecollection"
      Type="Lookup"
      Required="TRUE"/>
```

Only in the case that the field and the target list are both on the same site collection.
Let's say that I want to set a lookup pointing a field on a higher sitecollection, so I have to set a cross-site lookup.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

There no higher site collection in SharePoint. 
Maybe you mean web in higher level.
In SharePoint 2010 one of the ways to do it is to create site column in root web:
http://bramnuyts.be/en/2011/04/11/creating-a-cross-site-lookup-field-without-code/